Passing each lineitem of a JSON file in a loop
I need to pass a JSON file to the vendor and the vendor gives the token back when I pass the JSON file. I have the following class in order to achieve that:
public class PayParam
{
        public LineItemParam[] LineItems { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Email { get; set; }
        public string CustomerId { get; set; }
        public string CompanyName { get; set; }
}

 public class LineItemParam
    {
        public string Sku { get; set; }
        public string Description { get; set; }
        public decimal UnitPrice { get; set; }
        public int Quantity { get; set; }
    }

I am constructing a JSON by passing values to the class like this:
 var parameters = new PayParam();
      MailingInfo IdData = scData.FindData();
      
      string[] desc = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3};
      parameters = new PayParam
      {
         Phone = IdData.PhoneNumber,
         Email = IdData.Email.ToUpper(),
         CustomerId = "1234",
         CompanyName = "TEST NAME",
      },
        LineItems = new LineItemParam[]
          {
                  new LineItemParam
                          {
                              Sku = GetSKU(),
                              Description = "Test Desc",
                              UnitPrice =  12.00,
                              Quantity = 1
                          }
           }

The problem is, I need to pass multiple lineItem for each description so I need to do something like this:
parameters = new PayParam
      {
         Phone = IdData.PhoneNumber,
         Email = IdData.Email.ToUpper(),
         CustomerId = "1234",
         CompanyName = "TEST NAME",
      },
        foreach(var de in desc)
           {
               LineItems = new LineItemParam[]
               {
                  new LineItemParam
                          {
                              Sku = GetSKU(),
                              Description = de,
                              UnitPrice =  12.00,
                              Quantity = 1
                          }
               }

           }

The above code is not working, its throwing syntax error. It only works if I put separate line item like this:
parameters = new PayParam
      {
         Phone = IdData.PhoneNumber,
         Email = IdData.Email.ToUpper(),
         CustomerId = "1234",
         CompanyName = "TEST NAME",
      },
        
               LineItems = new LineItemParam[]
               {
                  new LineItemParam
                          {
                              Sku = GetSKU(),
                              Description = "Test1",
                              UnitPrice =  12.00,
                              Quantity = 1
                          },
                 new LineItemParam
                          {
                              Sku = GetSKU(),
                              Description = "Test2",
                              UnitPrice =  12.00,
                              Quantity = 1
                          }, 
                          
               }

I want to pass these lineItems in a loop and not write them individually.
any help will be appreciated.

Just use LINQ Select method to transform collection of descriptions into array of LineItemParams, like below:
parameters = new PayParam
{
    Phone = IdData.PhoneNumber,
    Email = IdData.Email.ToUpper(),
    CustomerId = "1234",
    CompanyName = "TEST NAME",
    LineItems = desc
        .Select(de => new LineItemParam
        {
            Sku = GetSKU(),
            Description = de,
            UnitPrice =  12.00,
            Quantity = 1
        }) 
        .ToArray(),
};


How do you know which price belongs to which description?

@iakobski, My mistake. Everything works fine now.
